# Too many initializer values; Initializing Dynamically Allocated Arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, initialization, allocation

Recently while going over C++, I dynamically allocated space for an array and tried to initialize it with 8 default values on the next line.

```
int* intArray = new int[8];
intArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
```

Visual Studio didn't like that, and underlined the **2** in red, as if there is a problem there, only to give me the error *"too many initializer values"*

I don't know if I used incorrect syntax or if you're just not allowed to set the value of an array that way after declaration. Any ideas?

*Okay, it seems this also isn't working for regular non-pointer arrays too, I must be just doing something dumb.*

Comment: `intArray` is not an array, it's a pointer. A pointer can't be initialized with an initializer list.

Comment: Try this: `int* intArray = new int[8] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};`

Comment: Okay, that definitely works, but what about when I just declare a regular array, why can't I use an initializer list on another line there as well? Or is that a pointer too?

Comment: Your assumption is correct.

Comment: Makes much more sense now. Thanks.

Comment: Use std::vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`intArray` is not an array, it's a pointer. A pointer can't be initialized with an initializer list.

Dynamic allocated memory can be initialized at the moment of allocation:

```
int* intArray = new int[8] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
```

C array can be initialized also at the declaration:

```
int intArray[8] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ allows static allocation without dimension parameter

```
int intArray[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
```

where for dynamic allocation

```
int *intArray = new int[8] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
```

the matching dimension must be passed.